# mongodb 3.2 java driver aggregation whith match on lookup

Tags: mongodb, lookup, mongo-java-driver

I wonder how to perform the aggregation $match on a $lookup collection with the **java driver for mongodb 3.2**. Here is the structure of the two collections i am working on :

```
coll_one:{
_id : ObjectId("hex_string"),
foreign_id : ObjectId("hex_string") **the id of coll_two**}

coll_two:{
_id : ObjectId("hex_string"),
actif : true,  
closed : false }
```

The lookup on the two ids (coll_one.foreign_id & coll_two._id) seems to work fine. But when i specify a match on coll_two.actif = true, it returns an empty result.

This is the Java code i'am using :

```
Bson lookup = new Document("$lookup", 
new Document("from", "coll_two"  )
.append("localField", "foreign_id")
.append("foreignField", "_id")
.append("as", "look_coll"));

List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<Bson>();
filters.add(lookup);

//here is the MATCH
filters.add(match(eq("look_coll.actif",true))); 

DB().getCollection("coll_one").aggregate(filters);
```

Evrything works fine whene i remove the match section. I have tried so many combination of possibilities with no success at all !!!

Can any body tells me if this is possible ????

Comment: Your code do works with the example data on my machine. Check your data is really what you expect it to be. For example, actif is boolean **true** not string "true". Also you can try to define the match stage just as a Document: `Bson match = new Document("$match", new Document("look_coll.actif", true));`

Answer (score 1):

Add your `$match` request to a `Document` instance :

```
Bson match = new Document("$match",
                new Document("look_coll.actif", true));

filters.add(match);
```

Here is a full example :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");

MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");

Bson lookup = new Document("$lookup",
        new Document("from", "coll_two")
                .append("localField", "foreign_id")
                .append("foreignField", "_id")
                .append("as", "look_coll"));

Bson match = new Document("$match",
        new Document("look_coll.actif", true));

List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();
filters.add(lookup);
filters.add(match);

AggregateIterable<Document> it = db.getCollection("coll_one").aggregate(filters);

for (Document row : it) {
    System.out.println(row.toJson());
}
```